# É possivel executar um listener quando o App não está sendo executado?

Tags: ios, swift, listener, background-services, local-notification

O App teria que comunicar ao usuário, que houve alteração de um valor no server, porém sem uso de Push Notification. Então pensei em adicionar um listener no iOS, e esse ao detectar a mudança do valor, iria disparar uma notificação local. E isso deverá ocorrer mesmo que o App não esteja sendo executado.

Alguém sabe por onde posso começar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode lançar a app em background, verificar o servidor e então disparar a notificação, usando background fetch.
Os passos são os seguintes:

1. Nas configurações do projeto, em *Capabilities*, habilite a seção *Background Modes* e selecione *Background fetch*.
2. Na classe AppDelegate, no método `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`
   você configura a frequência em que a app será chamada em background, através do método:
   `- (void)setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:(NSTimeInterval)minimumBackgroundFetchInterval`

Exemplo:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //...
    [application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];
    return YES;
}
```

3. Agora adicione na classe AppDelete o método `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler;`

Este método será chamado sempre que a app for lançada em background.
No fim da execução das operações é sempre necessário chamar o `completionHandler`, informando se a busca pelos dados foi bem sucedida. Exemplo:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

    /*
    ...
     */
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

Pra testar, você configura o target para lançar a app em modo background. Para isso, vá em *Product/Scheme/Manage Schemes*. Agora em *Run/Option*, marque *Launch due to a background fetch event*. 
Quando der build a app simulará o lançamento em background e assim você consegue testá-la sem ficar esperando o sistema fazer isso.

Comment: Estava lendo um tutorial sobre isso agora mesmo! Kkk obrigado mano!!! Ajudou muito. Somente uma duvida, que pode ser redundante, mas nao ficou claro isso para mim. O serviço executa mesmo que o App nao esteja sendo executado, e é possivel disparar uma Local Notification para informar ao usuario de novos dados disponivel?

Comment: Meu código entra antes de `completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData)`, correto?

Comment: Fiz um teste ajustando `[application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];` manualmente a cada 5 segundos para testes, mas ele somente dispara a notificação somente uma unica vez. Mesmo abrindo o App e fechando, ou colocando em segundo plano :/ Existe um modo de tornar esse processo recursivo? ( se auto chamar ao fim de cada verificação: 1-espera X tempo, 2- realiza consulta? notifica : não faz nada, 3 - auto chama)

Comment: De nada Tiago. Comentário 1: Sim, é possível lançar uma notificação local. Comentário 2: Sim, não se esqueça, caso a operação seja assíncrona (ex: requisição ao servidor), de chamar completionHandler só no final da mesma. Comentário 3: Não. Não adianta chamar esse método a toda hora. O sistema que decide quando abrir a app em background. Não dá pra controlar isso. Repare que o parâmetro é o tempo mínimo entre as chamadas. Não tem como controlar o máximo. Tipicamente vai levar mesmo bastante tempo entre as chamadas (horas/dias)

Comment: Obrigado ! Fiz mais algumas pesquisas aqui e realmente é isso mesmo.